# How CreatePrimitive custom object in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a conveyor belt system in unity, where I have a grid that all the objects will be placed on when I click there (it is from a tutorial video by jason weimanns). Right now it just makes cubes. Is there any way I could have a pre-made object with materials, textures and components and stuff, then copy it instead of the plain cube?

This is the relevant code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubePlacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Grid grid;

    private void Awake()
    {
        grid = FindObjectOfType<Grid>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
            {
                PlaceCubeNear(hitInfo.point);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PlaceCubeNear(Vector3 clickPoint)
    {
        var finalPosition = grid.GetNearestPointOnGrid(clickPoint);
        GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube).transform.position = finalPosition;

        //GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere).transform.position = nearPoint;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean is called a prefab in Unity.
Please take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html).

Basically you store a ready made object in your project (by dragging it from your hierarchy into a project folder for example) and create it using `GameObject.Instantiate(...)` instead of your `GameObject.CreatePrimitive(...)` call.

Modified code:

```
[SerializeField] GameObject prefabToBeUsed;

private void PlaceCubeNear(Vector3 clickPoint)
{
    Vector3 finalPosition = grid.GetNearestPointOnGrid(clickPoint);
    GameObject.Instantiate(prefabToBeUsed, finalPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: ok, so I replaced the CreatePrimitive with instantiate and put the finalPositon to the vector3 that i saw in the documentation, along with Quaternion.identity, but when I try to run it it says to fix all compiler errors even though it doesn't show the red text in the bottom, so I cant immediately see what's wrong                            
GameObject.Instatiate((conveyorside), (finalPosition), Quaternion.identity

Comment: If you get errors you have to provide the error message and the code producing it, otherwise we can not help you.

Comment: ok, Ill need to figure that out first. For some reason it wouldn't show the error in the console or at the bottom.

Comment: I updated the answer to contain your PlaceCubeNear method.

Comment: @Gubbadubba If it's the correct answer, please accept it as such.